# Get the previous element in a scope

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an exercice that makes me apply functions to elements (dynamically added) of a scope.
The functions apply to an item I performed a ng-click on.
Now, I have this :

```
console.log($scope.item)
```

What I would like to do is a print of the item that comes right before. The previous one. Is there some angular directive that helps retrieving it ?
So far, i've tried :

```
console.log($scope.previous.item)
console.log($scope.item.prev)
console.log($scope.item[$index -1])
```

None seems to be okay.

Comment: Can you post your complete code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what previous value in a scope variable is best to use $watch, where you can access the new and old values as parameters like below

```
$scope.$watch('yourVariable',function(newValue, oldValue){
//do your stuff
});
```